How to source a PowerShell script using CMake?
I have a Powershell script that calculates the semantic version using Git details. The script then writes the full SemVer and the Major.Minor.Patch as strings into environment variables. Eg 0.1.0-alpha+feature.IMVI-135.5169703.d
How can I run it before any target is created? Because I want to use it to set the version in the root project:
<Run Powershell script here>

project(MyCoolProject
  VERSION $ENV{MajorMinorPatch}
  DESCRIPTION "This is cool" 
  LANGUAGES CXX)

And then I can use definitions so that the .exe can output the version.
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
add_definitions( -DSEMANTIC_VERSION="$ENV{SemanticVersion}" )

I tried the following but nothing gets generated.
add_custom_target(findsemver ALL DEPENDS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/version.h)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT "version.h" COMMAND powershell "VersionInfoFromGit.ps1" WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} VERBATIM
COMMENT "=================== Generating SemVer Header file")


You probably search for execute_process CMake command, which executes the specified program/script immediately during the configuration stage. Not sure, however, whether setting of environment variable will remain after the script ends.
